# loading service with setTimeout test case not covered in angular 9?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How can i test below code it is not covered in code coverage.
Loading service with setTimeout test case not covered in angular 9.
i have tired out but it seems not covered. can anyone help me out with my code.

**LoadingService**

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoadingService {
  loaderText: any;
  get showLoader(): any {
    return this._showLoader;
  }
  set showLoader(newData: any) {
    this._showLoader = newData;
  }

  constructor() {}
  @Output() userChangeEvent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  _showLoader: boolean;
  setLoader(isShowLoader) {
    this.userChangeEvent.emit(isShowLoader);
  }

  getLoaderText(): any {
    return this.loaderText;
  }
  setLoaderText(text: any) {
    this.loaderText = text;
  }
}
```

**App.ts**

```js
this.loadinSrvc.userChangeEvent.subscribe((user) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showLoader = {
          text: this.loadinSrvc.getLoaderText() || 'Please wait...',
          isLoader: user,
        };
      })
    );
```

here is the **spec** file

```js
it(`should have as showloader configured`, async(() => {
      const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
      expect(app.showLoader).toEqual({
        isLoader: false,
        text: 'Please wait...',
      });
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `fakeAsync` zone method, and call `flush` to drain the macrotask queue until it is empty. Lots of fancy words, but basically this should work:

```
it(`should have as showloader configured`, fakeAsync(() => {
  const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  flush();

  expect(app.showLoader).toEqual({
   isLoader: false,
   text: 'Please wait...',
  });
}));
```